# How to set user agent of Http_client in netclient of ocamlnet?

Tags: ocaml

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but the [docs](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.6.1/doc/html-main/Http_client.html) aren't revealing me anything.

Solution or workaround would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use method `set_req_header : string -> string -> unit`:

```
let req = new Http_client.get (Neturl.string_of_url some_url) in
    req#set_req_header "User-Agent" "Your user agent";
```

And than make your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the ocamlnet is api is a little bit unusual for me.